# Terminal Errors When Using 'defaults'

Tags: terminal

I am trying to use

> defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES

in my terminal but when I do I get the following error:

> -bash: defaults: command not found

Any ideas as to what may be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Try "/usr/bin/defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES"   If that works, then you have an issue with your default path in the terminal shell.

Comment: (I just realized that "default path" in the above comment can be confusing, or a particularly cunning pun, depending on your point of view.  It was intended to be neither.  A less-confusing statement would be: "If that works, then you have an issue with the path variable that is set in your terminal shell")

Comment: @Kent just take credit for the pun, and be done with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my .bash_profile got corrupted. I went in via text edit and modified it to revert it to the default settings and all is well again